# How can we handle mixed Chinese glyphs/fonts?

Tags: chinese

We have several Word (docx) documents containing Chinese paragraphs.
For the Chinese parts the documents use mainly the fonts "MS Mincho" and "MS Gothic".
But for some glyphs the text changes to the font "Microsoft JhengHei".

How do we convert those documents to show all Chinese glyphs properly?

When converting the document to "tex" (via pandoc) we get the following which appears ok:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[]{IPAMincho}
\begin{document}
他向前走了一步，摸了一把脸上的雨水和泪水，等呜咽声从喉咙里咽下去以后，才继续说：
这些年来，我给大家办的事太少了，许多乡亲们直到现在还少吃没穿的，我对不起乡亲们！
\end{document}
```

But when converting to "PDF" (via xelatex) some characters (the Microsoft JhengHei) are not displayed (in yellow). The PDF is as follows:

[image]

These (marked) are the glyphs that change to "Microsoft JhengHei" and are not printed in PDF:

```
他向前走了一步，摸了一把脸上的雨水和泪水，等呜咽声从喉咙里咽下去以后，才继续说：
---------------------^----------------^-------^----------------^^^ 
这些年来，我给大家办的事太少了，许多乡亲们直到现在还少吃没穿的，我对不起乡亲们！
^----------^----^-----------^--^^^^-----^--^-------------^----^^^
```

We use `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)` on Debian 11.

Comment: Is it a matter of employing fonts that furnish either traditional-Chinese (TC) or simplified-Chinese (SC) glyphs? I don't have `IPAMincho` on my system (MacOS 13.1/ MacTeX2022/ XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994), so I can't test your setup directly. That said, if I employ [NotoSerifTC-Regular](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+TC), I can reproduce the screenshot you posted almost exactly, whereas if I switch to [NotoSerifSC-Regular](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+SC), the output looks just fine. Both Noto fonts may be downloaded from https://fonts.google.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX (with its variants, here XeTeX) is aimed to *typesetting*, not just at showing something on the screen.

For this reason it *never* substitutes font families. In LaTeX it's possible that a missing shape or weight is substituted, but always following some rule. When processing your document you get

```
Missing character: There is no 脸 (U+8138) in font IPAMincho/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;!
```

and similar messages for the other missing characters.

If I run `albatross -b 3 脸` on my machine, I get

```
        __ __           __
.---.-.|  |  |--.---.-.|  |_.----.-----.-----.-----.
|  _  ||  |  _  |  _  ||   _|   _|  _  |__ --|__ --|
|___._||__|_____|___._||____|__| |_____|_____|_____|

                    Unicode code point [4EEC] mapping to 们                    
                                                                               
  Font name                                                                    
  .Hiragino Sans GB Interface                                                  
  .LastResort                                                                  
  .PingFang HK,.蘋方\-港,.苹方\-港                                             
  .PingFang SC,.蘋方\-簡,.苹方\-简                                             
  .PingFang TC,.蘋方\-繁,.苹方\-繁                                             
  AR PL KaitiM GB,文鼎ＰＬ简中楷                                               
  AR PL SungtiL GB,文鼎ＰＬ简报宋                                              
  Arial Unicode MS                                                             
  FandolFang,FandolFang R                                                      
  FandolHei                                                                    
  FandolKai                                                                    
  FandolSong                                                                   
  GB18030 Bitmap                                                               
  Heiti SC,黑體\-簡,黒体\-簡,Heiti\-간체,黑体\-简                              
  Heiti TC,黑體\-繁,黒体\-繁,Heiti\-번체,黑体\-繁                              
  Hiragino Sans GB,冬青黑體簡體中文,ヒラギノ角ゴ                               
  簡体中文,冬青黑体简体中文,Hiragino Sans GB W3,冬青黑體簡體中文               
  W3,ヒラギノ角ゴ 簡体中文 W3,冬青黑体简体中文 W3                              
  Hiragino Sans GB,冬青黑體簡體中文,ヒラギノ角ゴ                               
  簡体中文,冬青黑体简体中文,Hiragino Sans GB W6,冬青黑體簡體中文               
  W6,ヒラギノ角ゴ 簡体中文 W6,冬青黑体简体中文 W6                              
  PingFang HK,蘋方\-港,苹方\-港                                                
  PingFang SC,蘋方\-簡,苹方\-简                                                
  PingFang TC,蘋方\-繁,苹方\-繁                                                
  Songti SC,宋體\-簡,宋体\-简                                                  
  Songti TC,宋體\-繁,宋体\-繁                                                  
  STSong
```

If I replace `IPAMincho` with `FandolFang`, I get

[image]

Below the output with `FandolSong` instead

[image]

Ensure that the Chinese font covers the needed characters.

Comment: with lualatex you could define a fallback (but I have no idea if this is what chinese typesetting would recommend ...)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe for the purpose of showing a Web page, not for serious typesetting. I've seen enough “books” where random font substitutions happened, even with sans serif replacing serif for one or two letters in a word.

Comment: well lualatex wouldn't replace by a random font, you have to setup the fallback. But you are quite right that one should be careful.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. It appears that the used font "IPAMincho" doesn't cover all the needed glyphs. I replaced it with "UMingHK" and it works as expected. "DroidSansFallback" solves the issue too.